# How to remove duplicate characters from a string in Java

Tags: java

I just want to get help on removing duplicates. So far I have this, but it doesn't delete or remove the words that occured many times.

```
 void antUnikOrd() {
int unikCount = 0;
String c = "ahfuwa";
for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {


    for(int j= 0;j<a.length;j++) {  
    if(a[i].equals(a[j])) {         
        unikCount++;
    }
    if(unikCount>1) {
        a[j] = c;
        unikCount = 1;

    }       
      unikCount = 0;            
    }

    for( i = 0;i<a.length;i++) {
    //if(a[i] != " ") {
    System.out.println(a[i]);
    //  }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're expecting removing them from memory to remove them from a file?

Comment: Would you like us to write the function for you, or do you have any question concerning your particular attempt?

Comment: people tend to use regular expressions for these requirements.

Comment: This code neither reads or writes to file.

Comment: what is the variable 'a'?

Comment: One of your comments hints at the fact that you are not allowed to use a Set. This implies that you are trying to get us to do your homework. Please read this: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1. While people are more than willing to help, they are not willing to do your work for you

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use extra memory, and the very convinient Sets of Java then there is an implace algo to do what you want that is O(NlogN) instead of the obvious O(N^2) solution you propose.

```
1 - Sort the array of words (Arrays.sort(~) will do the trick in O(nlogn)).
2 - For each word in the sorted array look if the next one is equal. (one loop)
    a - TRUE = set to delete current word from array (not the next one, keep that one)
    b - FALSE = go on to next
3 - Write to file by ignoring the detect duplicates. (one more loop)
```

To explain point 2 :

```
array = [ a, b, b, c, d, d, d ]
ITERATIONS
- a != b ->  [ a, b, b, c, d, d, d ] index = 0
- b == b ->  [ a, X, b, c, d, d, d ] index = 1
- ...
- d == d ->  [ a, X, b, c, X, d, d ] index = 4
- d == d ->  [ a, X, b, c, X, X, d ] index = 5
- d is last so we stop
```

now we filter the Xs:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

This is actually O(nlogn + 2n) which can be simplified to O(nlogn).

Good luck with the implementation but it should be fairly simple.
If you cannot use Arrays.sort(~) implement your own sort function, I suggest QuickSort or MergeSort since they dictate the overall performance of this solution.

Comment: we need to use just for and if with arrays to get the answers. I used parallel arrays to start it off with. but cant get it right

Comment: my solution uses exactly that

Comment: set the detected duplicates to null and ignore them when writing back to file? Since it seems to be homework I can give you this but won't put code.

Answer (score 0):

You can store elements into HashSet that automatically deletes repetition

Comment: Expand this answer to link it more specifically to this question. OPs issue is with writing back to the file.

Comment: we are not allowed to use hashset,map or arraylist. So I need to use this. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You could add strings into HashSet, it removes duplicates.

Comment: void lesFraFil() {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int count;
 
     System.out.println("Gi navnet til filen: ");
     String filNavn = sc.next();

     try{
  File k = new File(filNavn);
  Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(k);
  count = 0;
  while(sc2.hasNext()) {
      count++;
      sc2.next();
  }
  Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(k);
  a = new String[count];
  tempAry = new String[count];
  for(int i = 0;i<count;i++) {
      a[i] =sc3.next().toLowerCase();
      tempAry[i] = a[i];
      // System.out.println(a[i]+a.length);
  }
 
  
  
     }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
     }

Answer (score 0):

When you're replacing the text in a file, I often read the whole file into memory, do whatever manipulations I want to do, then write it all back to the file. I don't like handing out the answer, so I'll give you something similar. For example in pseudocode:

```
public void removeWord(String word)
{
    fileReader := FileReader(the file to read)
    lines := Java HashSet object
    for every line in the file {
        // Cycle through each line and load into the HashSet
        lines.add(current line)
    }

    // You now have a whole bunch of different lines.

    fileReader.close();
    // Unlock the file.

    fileWriter := FileWriter(the file to write in overwrite mode)

    for every line in lines
    {
         fileWriter.write(line)
    }
    fileWriter.flush() // To be safe..
    fileWriter.close() // to prevent memory leaks.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is slightly unclear but I will assume that you wish to read the contents of a file, remove duplicates and write it back to a file.

Once you have the contents of the file (please see this question for guidelines: [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)) then the easiest way to remove duplicates from a List is to put them into a Set:

```
List<String> lines = readFromFile(); // complete this method
Set<String> uniqueLines = new HashSet<String>(lines);
```

Once you have a set of unique lines, you can simply write them back to a file (please see this question for guidelines: [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file))